# How to avoid DRY in PostgreSQL with a nested query

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query works fine in this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT inv.move_id,
                inv.client_id, 
                inv.reference,
                inv.date_inv,  
                inv.amount,
                inv.state,
                inv.client_type,
                inv.agent_id,
                (
                      SELECT SUM(nc.amount) AS total
                      FROM invoice nc
                      WHERE nc.journal = 15
                      AND nc.ref_move = inv.move_id
                      AND nc.state = inv.state
                ) AS credit, ( 
                      SELECT SUM(ip.amount)
                      FROM inv_payment ip
                      WHERE inv.reference = ip.reference
                ) AS paid,
                (inv.amount) - (
                  coalesce((
                    SELECT SUM(nc.amount) AS total
                    FROM invoice nc
                    WHERE nc.journal = 15
                    AND nc.ref_move = inv.move_id
                    AND nc.state = inv.state
                  ), 0) + coalesce((
                    SELECT SUM(ip.amount)
                    FROM inv_payment ip
                    WHERE inv.reference = ip.reference
                  ), 0)
                ) AS outstanding
FROM invoice inv
  INNER JOIN inv_move im ON im.id = inv.move_id
  INNER JOIN client cl ON cl.id = inv.client_id 
WHERE inv.agent_id = '%'
  AND inv.date_inv
    BETWEEN '%' AND '%'
  AND inv.state = 'open'
ORDER BY inv.agent_id
```

I'm trying to DRY doing this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT inv.move_id,
                    inv.client_id, 
                    inv.reference,
                    inv.date_inv,  
                    inv.amount,
                    inv.state,
                    inv.client_type,
                    inv.agent_id,
                    (
                      SELECT SUM(nc.amount) AS total
                      FROM invoice nc
                      WHERE nc.journal = 15
                      AND nc.ref_move = inv.move_id
                      AND nc.state = inv.state
                    ) AS credit, ( 
                      SELECT SUM(ip.amount)
                      FROM inv_payment ip
                      WHERE inv.reference = ip.reference
                    ) AS paid,
                    (inv.amount) - (
                      coalesce((credit), 0) + coalesce((paid), 0)
                    ) AS outstanding
    FROM invoice inv
      INNER JOIN inv_move im ON im.id = inv.move_id
      INNER JOIN client cl ON cl.id = inv.client_id 
    WHERE inv.agent_id = '%'
      AND inv.date_inv
        BETWEEN '%' AND '%'
      AND inv.state = 'open'
    ORDER BY inv.agent_id
```

But I'm getting an error in this way.
Because I want to use the alias column for operation values in other column.
How could I do it? 
I was trying to use a WITH PostgreSQL statement but I couldn't find a better solution in that way.

Comment: Unrelated, but using DISTINCT like that is bad for data quality. It leads to confusing/surprising results when columns are added or removed from the query. It also masks logic problems. If you're getting multiple rows that you don't expect, look at your joins and figure out where they're coming from. Frequently the problem is a join criteria isn't strict enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **CANT** use a field calculated on the same level.

```
SELECT 1 + 2  as three, three * 2 as six
                        ^^^^^
                        undefined
```

So either you create a subquery.

```
SELECT three*2 as six
FROM ( SELECT 1 + 2 as three
       FROM table
     ) T
```

or for your example use a `JOIN`

using CTE:

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT ref_move, state, SUM(nc.amount) AS total
    FROM invoice nc
    WHERE nc.journal = 15
    GROUP BY ref_move, state 
)
SELECT *
FROM invoice i 
JOIN cte c
  ON i.ref_move= c.ref_move
 AND i.state  = c.state
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery in FROM:

```
SELECT *, amount-credit-paid AS outstanding FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT inv.move_id,
            inv.client_id, 
            inv.reference,
            inv.date_inv,  
            inv.amount,
            inv.state,
            inv.client_type,
            inv.agent_id,
            (
                  SELECT SUM(nc.amount) AS total
                  FROM invoice nc
                  WHERE nc.journal = 15
                  AND nc.ref_move = inv.move_id
                  AND nc.state = inv.state
            ) AS credit, ( 
                  SELECT SUM(ip.amount)
                  FROM inv_payment ip
                  WHERE inv.reference = ip.reference
            ) AS paid
    FROM invoice inv ...
) AS _;
```